# Converting nested json data to csv using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a JSON data like the below:

```
jsonStr = '''
{
    "student_details": [
        {
            "ID": 101,
            "Name": [
                {
                    "First_Name": "AAA",
                    "Last_Name": "BBB"
                },
                {
                    "Father": "AAA1",
                    "Mother": "BBB1"
                }
            ],
            "Phone_Number": [
                {
                    "Student_PhoneNum1": 1111111111,
                    "Student_PhoneNum2": 1111111112
                },
                {
                    "Parent_PhoneNum1": 1111111121,
                    "Parent_PhoneNum2": 1111111132
                }
            ],
            "DOB": "1998-05-05",
            "Place_of_Birth": "AA",
            "Marks": [
                {
                    "DataStructures": 95,
                    "ObjectOrientedProgramming": 85,
                    "DiscreteMathematics": 100,
                    "AnalysisOfAlgorithm": 99,
                    "NetworkSecurity": 85
                }
            ],
            "DateOfJoining": "2022-05-05"
        },
        {
            "ID": 102,
            "Name": [
                {
                    "First_Name": "ZZZ",
                    "Last_Name": "YYY"
                },
                {
                    "Father": "ZZZ1",
                    "Mother": "YYY1"
                }
            ],
            "Phone_Number": [
                {
                    "Student_PhoneNum1": 1111111182,
                    "Student_PhoneNum2": 1111111182
                },
                {
                    "Parent_PhoneNum1": 1111111128,
                    "Parent_PhoneNum2": 1111111832
                }
            ],
            "DOB": "1998-06-10",
            "Place_of_Birth": "ZZ",
            "Marks": [
                {
                    "DataStructures": 25,
                    "ObjectOrientedProgramming": 50,
                    "DiscreteMathematics": 75,
                    "AnalysisOfAlgorithm": 60,
                    "NetworkSecurity": 30
                }
            ],
            "DateOfJoining": "2022-05-05"
        },
        {
            "ID": 103,
            "Name": [
                {
                    "First_Name": "TTT",
                    "Last_Name": "UUU"
                },
                {
                    "Father": "TTT1",
                    "Mother": "UUU1"
                }
            ],
            "Phone_Number": [
                {
                    "Student_PhoneNum1": 1111118753,
                    "Student_PhoneNum2": 1111111153
                },
                {
                    "Parent_PhoneNum1": 1111111523,
                    "Parent_PhoneNum2": 1111111533
                }
            ],
            "DOB": "1999-01-01",
            "Place_of_Birth": "TT",
            "Marks": [
                {
                    "DataStructures": 50,
                    "ObjectOrientedProgramming": 75,
                    "DiscreteMathematics": 65,
                    "AnalysisOfAlgorithm": 75,
                    "NetworkSecurity": 40
                }
            ],
            "DateOfJoining": "2022-05-06"
        }
    ]
}
'''
```

I'm trying to convert every key-value pair to a csv file from this data using the below code

```
import pandas as pd

ar  = pd.read_json(jsonStr)
df = pd.json_normalize(ar['student_details'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('CSVresult.csv', index=False)
```

for accessing the JSON data, I have passed json data header named `student_details`.

Result:
[image: csv]

is there any way to get the data like the below(every key-value pairs in separate columns) without passing the header `student_details` and the column names directly?(the json data contain a lot of nested data like this)

[image: csv2]

Comment: How would you like `Marks` to be displayed? a column for each subject as well?

Comment: a column for each subject as well? - yes

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonStr)
df=df['student_details'].apply(pd.Series).explode('Name').explode('Phone_Number').explode('Marks')

for row in df.to_dict('records'):
    row['Name']['ID']=row['ID']
    row['Phone_Number']['ID']=row['ID']


def get_values_without_nans(col_name):
    return df[col_name].apply(pd.Series).drop_duplicates().groupby("ID").agg(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().all() else x.dropna())

name = get_values_without_nans('Name')
phone_number=get_values_without_nans('Phone_Number')
phone_number.index=phone_number.index.astype('int32')

marks=df.set_index('ID').Marks.apply(pd.Series).drop_duplicates()
meta=df[['ID','DOB','Place_of_Birth','DateOfJoining']].drop_duplicates().set_index('ID')
final=meta.join([name,phone_number,marks])
print(final)
'''
    ID  DOB Place_of_Birth  DateOfJoining   First_Name  Last_Name   Father  Mother  Student_PhoneNum1   Student_PhoneNum2   Parent_PhoneNum1    Parent_PhoneNum2    DataStructures  ObjectOrientedProgramming   DiscreteMathematics AnalysisOfAlgorithm
0   101 1998-05-05  AA  2022-05-05  AAA BBB AAA1    BBB1    1111111111.0    1111111112.0    1111111121.0    1111111132.0    95  85  100 99
1   102 1998-06-10  ZZ  2022-05-05  ZZZ YYY ZZZ1    YYY1    1111111182.0    1111111182.0    1111111128.0    1111111832.0    25  50  75  60
2   103 1999-01-01  TT  2022-05-06  TTT UUU TTT1    UUU1    1111118753.0    1111111153.0    1111111523.0    1111111533.0    50  75  65  75

'''
```